# Showing menus, based on menuIds using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show menus on the homepage(index.html), based on the menuIds.

The menuIds are fetched based on the users role, through a http request to the backend server, when the user logins.

I am setting these menuIds in cookies (login.js)

ng-if directive is used to hide/show specific menus.

Here is the index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="InvoiceApp">
    <head>
        <title>Invoicing System</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular-1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular-1.2.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <link href='/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular-1.2.6/angular-cookies.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/finance/js/adjustments-controllers.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/finance/js/invoice-controllers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/finance/js/finance-services.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" >
        <link href='/css/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='/css/dashboard.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fuild">
            <div class="row header">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <img src="/img/rbOutlineLogo.png" height="64px" style = "margin-top:15px; margin-left:20px"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10" style="margin-top:15px">
                    <img src="/img/cis_logo_new.png" height="64px">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row body">
                <div class="col-lg-2" ng-controller="SidebarCtrl">
                    <div class="nav">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="padding-top:7px">
                            <li class="dropdown navBarStyle" ng-if = "**menuList.indexOf(1) !== -1**">

                                <a href class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                                      View Invoice
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="menu">
                                    <li class="navBarStyle">
                                        <a href="#/viewByBOCode">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">
                                                By BO Code & Date Range
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="navBarStyle">
                                        <a href="#/viewByInvoiceNumber">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">
                                                By Invoice Number
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li  class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "**menuList.indexOf(2)** !== -1">
                                <a href="#/configureBO">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                      Configure BO
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "**menuList.indexOf(3)** !== -1">
                                <a href="#/approveBO">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                      Configure BO Status
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "**menuList.indexOf(4)** !== -1">
                                <a href class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                                    Download Reports
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="menu">
                                    <li class="navBarStyle">
                                        <a href="#/generateReport">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
                                            Invoice & Transaction History Reports
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="navBarStyle">
                                        <a href="#/yourBusPendingAdjustmentMemos">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
                                            YourBus Pending Adjustment Memos
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(5) !== -1">
                                <a href="#/uploadExcelFile">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
                                     Upload Payment Details
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(6) !== -1">
                                <a href="#/summary/operator/">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                     Operator Dashboard
                                </a>
                            </li>
                           <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(7) !== -1">
                               <a href="#/adjusmentsMemo">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                                      Create Adjustment Memo
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(8) !== -1">
                                <a href class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                                      Advance Payment Adjustments
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked"
                                    ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(9) !== -1 || menuList.indexOf(10) !== -1 || menuList.indexOf(11) !== -1" role="menu">
                                    <li class="navBarStyle"
                                        ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(9) !== -1">
                                        <a href="#/doAdvancePayment">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                              Do Adjustment
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(10) !== -1">
                                        <a href="#/approveAdvanceAdjustment">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                              Approve Adjustments
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="navBarStyle"
                                        ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(11) !== -1">
                                        <a href="#/approvedAdvanceAdjustments">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                                View Approved Adjustments
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li  class="dropdown navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(12) !== -1">
                                <a href class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                                      Other Adjustments
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked"
                                    ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(13) !== -1 || menuList.indexOf(14) !== -1 || menuList.indexOf(15) !== -1 || menuList.indexOf(16) !== -1" role="menu">
                                    <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(13) !== -1">
                                        <a href="#/doOtherAdjustments">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                                Do Adjustments for Today
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(14) !== -1">
                                        <a href="#/viewAdjustments">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                                View Adjustments
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(15) !== -1">
                                        <a href="#/invoiceAdjustments">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                              Approve Adjustments
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="navBarStyle" ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(16) !== -1">
                                        <a href="#/approvedOtherAdjustments">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                                View Approved Adjustments
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(17) !== -1" style="background-color: #eee; border-radius:5px">
                                <a href="#/generateInvoice"> 
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>  
                                     Generate Invoice
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#/logout">
                                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>
                                    Logout
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a target="_blank" href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/12MMSYpfvCI0A694L5ujOnHziOU71Mhce-iRx99jeFU8/pub?embedded=true">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
                                    FAQ
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10" style="border-left: 1px solid #F0EDED; min-height:528px">
                    <div ng-view>This is main page.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row footer" style="padding:10px">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span>
                <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> ibibogroup All rights reserved
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the login.js logic to fetch the menuIds based on the user :

```
var url = '/api/user/login/ui';
        $http.post(url, {
            userName: $scope.credential.email,
            password: $scope.credential.password
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            **$cookies.menuList = data;
            $window.location.href = 'index.html';**
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (status === 400) {
                $scope.errors.push("Invalid Credential, please try again.");
            } else {
                $scope.errors.push("Service not available currently, please try again after some time.");
            }
        });
```

Here is the controller for the index.html

```
angular.module('**InvoiceControllers**', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('**SidebarCtrl**', function($scope, $cookies, $log, $window) {
    **$scope.menuList = [];
    $scope.menuList = $cookies.permissions;**
    $log.info($scope.menuList);
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.menuList)) {
        $window.location.href = 'login.html';
    }
 });
```

But upon loading the index.html, 
the snippet -> `ng-if = "menuList.indexOf(menu_id) !== -1"`
is not working.

What i am doing woring here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use by this way

```
data-ng-if = "menuList.map(function(x) {return x.id; }).indexOf(menu_id) != -1"
```

But better thing if you use method

```
data-ng-if = "getMenuStatus(menu_id)"

$scope.getMenuStatus = function(menu_id)
{
  return menuList.map(function(x) {return x.id; }).indexOf(menu_id) !== -1;
}
```

I think it will work

Comment: Yes this suggestion helped. The snippet -> **$scope.menuList = [];
    $scope.menuList = $cookies.permissions;** was not constructed into an array.